# htaccess redirect not working. gives 404

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using slim framework and it has following `.htaccess`

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L,B,QSA,NE]
</IfModule>
```

I'm migrating an old site  which has urls like `index.php?q=about`.

Now I want both `index.php?q=about` and `/about/` to go to same page. So I tried this

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=
Rewriterule ^index.php?q=(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [R=301,NC,B,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L,B,QSA,NE]
</IfModule>
```

But I'm getting `404` error. Can anybody help me out?

Update:
`mod_rewrite` is enabled and `/about/` is working fine. I need `index.php?q=about` to show the same page.

Comment: Does your server have `mode_rewrite` enabled and turned on?

Comment: Yes `/about/` is working fine

Comment: try something like this then: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L]`

Comment: @Latheesan that totally will not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect /index.php?q=about to /about
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?q=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```